# way to implement right logic for FILTER with PAGING in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

i have an issue with logic in ASP.NET web site - (gridview - filter - paging)

filter component
    -------
gridview component
    -------
paging component
    -------

Question: 
Full list of result shows '1 of 25 pages' on first load.
If I choose filter by some condition - it shows result '1 of 5 pages'.
And if i use paging (to go to 5 (last) page) - filter is crashed and shows 5 of 25 pages.

How to implement right logic for FILTER with PAGING in gridview?

With regards!

Comment: You will probably need to post some code as there could be many ways of achieving this. Otherwise I suggest just comparing what you have with this link: http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/031506-1.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that the pager generates HTTP GET links with jsut the page as parameter, so your form values are all lost.

You can solve it like [this article](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/180/Displaying-Search-Results-In-A-WebGrid) proposes with intercepting the click on the link with jquery and submitting the form instead.

Or you can solve it simply by changing the method of your search form to `GET`. The pager just appends the `page` parameter to the current url, so your filter parameters will be send back to the action in that case. This approach is shown in detail in [this article](http://www.mikepope.com/blog/DisplayBlog.aspx?permalink=2377).